# The variety generated by a subalgebra of a Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra and $A$ be its subalgebra. The claim is the variety generated by $A$ is the class of all Boolean algebras. I can give the following proof for it but I think this claim is not true. Please let me know if this proof is true. If that is false please show me the mistake.

Let $B_2$ be the Boolean algebra with two elements. Then $V(B_2)$ is the set of all Boolean algebras, as it is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2339222/144897) by the following argument:

1. Every variety is generated by is subdirectly irreducible members.
2. $B_2$  is the only subdirectly irreducible member of the variety axiomatized by the identities of Boolean algebra.

Now we know that $B_2$ is a subalgebra of $A$ (my doubt is here but I can not refuse that) and so $B_2\in V(A)$. Therefore $V(B_2)\subseteq V(A)$. But, since $V(B_2)$ is the set of all Boolean algebras, we conclude that $V(A)$ is also the set of all Boolean algebras.

To make it more clarify why I think that this can't be true is that in the page 110 of the paper "[Pretabular varieties of modal algebras](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00370315)" of Block, $A$ is a subalgebra of a Boolean algebra $\mathcal{F}^+$ but he uses the variety $V(A)$ without mentioning that $V(A)$ is the class of all Boolean algebras.

Comment: The result is true, unless $B$ is a one-element Boolean algebra. If $0\neq1$ in $B$, then the same applies in any of its sub-algebras. Thus every sub-algebra $A$ of $B$ does have $B_2$ as a sub-algebra.

Comment: @amrsa Thanks. I added a paragraph to clarify why I think the proof may not be correct.

Comment: In the context of the book you refer to, is $\mathcal F^+$ just a Boolean algebra, or a modal algebra (i.e., a Boolean algebra with modal operators added)? It's not the same, and depending on the context, there may be proper sub-varieties.

Comment: @amrsa, Yes you are right. $F^+$ is a modal algebra. Now, would you please help me to solve the question in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235668/the-free-object-of-the-variety-constructed-by-an-m-generated-subalgebra)